# GetResponse and GetRequestStream from one WebRequest

Tags: c#

I am writing an application that connects to a web page and downloads a few things on that page. I got that part working. My problem is that the page doesn't display all content from the start. It loads a portion of the page with a button at the bottom that you need to click to display more content. I know that the button does a ajax call to the server to get the rest of the page.

I have two pieces of code. The one downloads the web page as it is and the other does the ajax call and get the next portion of the page.

The problem is that I don't know how long the page actually is and I'll need to press the button every time to get the next bit of the page.

So my actual question is: How do you make a WebRequest, get the response and create a new request?

PS: the URL never changes. No matter how many time you press the button, it only loads more data, keeping the URL the same.

```
// variable to store all HTML code
string EVERYTHING;

// Get the first bit of the page
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.webPageURL.com");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
System.IO.Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream);
EVERYTHING = reader.ReadToEnd();

// Press the button and get the second bit of the page
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.webPageURL.com");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"/browse_ajax?action_continuation=1&amp;continuation=CjgSGFVDQjBsaXQyZ2lOZmZsMWhpMWE0azZBZxocRWdaMmFXUmxiM01nQURBQ09BRmdBV29BZWdFeg%253D%253D");
    stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    EVERYTHING += Environment.NewLine + reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that what you wrote should really be your request stream? It looks more like a GET request. Should the button press url be "http:// www.webPageURL.com/browse_ajax" and the request stream the form-urlencoded parameters?

Comment: The first bit of code is a "GET" request. I didn't specify that in my code since the default HttpWebRequest Method is "GET".

Comment: I'm talking about your second request, which is a POST. But it doesn't look correct to me. If you look at the wiki article about [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) then you'll see that it is different to what you write. The first part ("/browse_ajax") should be a part of the URL, not part of the parameters. You could also use a browser and check the actual queries in the debugging view.

Comment: I tried putting "/browse_ajax" at the end of the URL but that takes me to another page (one that I'm not interested in). As I mentioned, the code works and it gets all the info that I need. I just can't press the button again, even though I need to. What I need is (1) a way to do the HttpWebRequest, (2) get get server reply in a string variable, (3) do a post, append the server reply to the string variable. Step 2 and 3 should go in a loop function. I hope this explains it a bit better?